# 12.04 server runs into grub "unknown symbol type" problem and I get stuck in grub rescue, how do I fix it?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, grubrescue

When I try to boot I get stuck in a grub rescue prompt, with the messgae:

```
error: unknown symbol type '13'.

grub rescue> _
```

I hard rebooted the server over PuTTY, with the standard reboot command (I think).

How can I fix this and get my server to boot, since it runs my website?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command:

```
update-grub
```

Comment: Unknown command 'update-grub'
      
Btw: I don't have access to the terminal, this is still in the boot screen.

Comment: I would boot from a Live CD and run 'Boot-Repair'. You can find general instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I put in the original self-burned Live CD and it will not go past the "Loading bootlogo..." text. I do not believe it is a problem with the CD, but if so, how do I check it?

Comment: You can put the disk into another computer to see if it works there.